# Outlook Office 365: Encrypt all outgoing messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption

According to this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc#ID0EBBD=Newer_versions

> When you choose to encrypt all outgoing messages by default, you can write and send messages the same as with any other messages, but all potential recipients must have your digital ID to decode or view your messages.

Why?
Normally encryption works so, that I have the RECIPIENTS certificate (public key). Recipient does not need to have anything from me, unless they need to encrypt the reply.

"Digital ID" is ambiguous at least for me in this context.

Comment: "Why?" - Why do your recipients need the ability to decode your encrypted email? Because without the ability to decode your encrypted email they won't be able to read your email.  "Recipient does not need to have anything from me, unless they need to encrypt the reply." - This assumption is incorrect. By having your digital ID they have the information (the certificate) required to decode your message.  [digital ID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-digital-id-0eaa0ab9-b8a2-4a7e-828b-9bded6370b7b). It basically means all recipients have a copy of your public key.

Comment: That is kinda in contradiction to what I understand of asynchronous encryption. Normally I would need the RECIPIENTS public key to encrypt my message for them. I an order to decrypt my message the recipient needs theirs private key + password. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

> When you choose to encrypt all outgoing messages by default, you can write and send messages the same as with any other messages, but all potential recipients must have your digital ID to decode or view your messages.

This really makes no sense for S/MIME. I *suspect* it might be related to "Microsoft 365 Message Encryption (Information Rights Management)", which is a kind of DRM scheme that was introduced in Office 2003? Either that, or the docs are just wrong.

> "Digital ID" is ambiguous at least for me in this context.

"Digital ID" is Microsoft's term for an S/MIME certificate. (Microsoft has been using S/MIME for a *long* time.)

Answer (score 0):

The text is correct, and these are two different mechanisms that
have different aims :

- You encrypt a message with a recipients public key.
  This means that only he can read the message, by using his secret
  private key.
- You encrypt your message with your secret private key.
  This means that any recipient that has your public key can read
  the message by using the key. This provides a digital signature
  for you, but is not secret. Recipients that don't have your public key
  cannot read the message.